# CSS not working on the left sidebar but on the upper bar

Tags: html, css, hover

The code given below is working on the upper bar, but it will not work on the left bar.

```css
#one {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
}
#two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <p>mango</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>apple</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code works if the mango is on the top and it will not work when the mango is on the left side.

Comment: can you add the image how you want to design ?

Comment: #one {
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
    width:10%;
    height: 100%;
}

#two {
  opacity: 0;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

```css
#one {
  width:100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
#two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div id="one">
    <p>mango</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>apple</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the sidebar ? there is only two container set to block.

```css
#one {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
}
#two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <p>mango</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>apple</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i want to do it with some percentage values(width n height)

Comment: #one { display:block; background-color: red; width:10%; height: 100%; } #two { opacity: 0; width:20%; height:100%; background-color: green; position: relative; top: -34px; }